# ExecutorService with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm working on a java web-socket application, in which I will be expecting a reply from a service. I've used `ExecutorService` & `FutureTask` to submit the tasks. I need to continuously hit the service until I get the response, If I don't get the response in 5 mins, I need to cancel the service call and go to the next task. I'm calling the code in while loop, I don't know how to stop the execution after 5 mins. So getting out of memory issue.

Am trying this POC on JBoss server.  I'm creating the executor service and submitting the request.

First call:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
Future<UserData> futureResult = executorService
                                .submit(new WebSocketPoolingThread(request));
```

`WebSocketPoolingThread` is a callable class where I will be calling the server which expects a response

```
public List<Response> call() throws Exception {
   //call server till get success response 
   //if not stop the call in 5 mins
}
```

And am getting the response in ,

```
if (futureData.isDone()){
   UserData = futureData.get();
}
```

As of now, am calling the "First call" in while loop.  I need to stop it based on the above condition. Please help me or suggest me any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: By calling first call in loop, you are repeatedly creating 50 threads and that is causing out of memory

Comment: Yes, i know the reason, but I want to know how do I stop it? or any better way to implement.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish?  I'm having a hard time figuring out the overall goal.

Comment: To make it simple, i have a java websocket class which needs to interact with my class, in which I need to call a service which needs to be called every second and it has to wait for the response.  I need to cancel the action if I get the response back, else in 5mins I will have to cancel it.

Comment: Kind of Java Polling that am trying to implement.